# Partitions are gone

Tags: 13.10, windows-xp, testdisk

I know this question has been asked many no.of times & I'm asking again please don't mark it as duplicate. I had installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my sister's laptop & now Ubuntu has deleted all the partitions which were there earlier in Windows. Now I'm going to remove Ubuntu & go back to Windows. 
I heard there is an tool called "TestDisk" which is also available for Windows. If I intall Windows & partition the drive & use "TestDisk" application will it be able to recover all the data that was lost due to installation of Ubuntu.
Now I'm in desperate need for help. I hope you people can help me & save me from embracement. Eagerly waiting for your responses.

Comment: since you're using `Ubuntu` there is a good software to recover data. I recommend you to first use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) while using Ubuntu. If that fails then you can install windows and there are a log of recovery tools like **i-Care** and many more that would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* install Windows first. That will overwrite more files, reducing the chance you'll be able to recover your files. Instead, use `photorec` from the `testdisk` package while running Ubuntu from a live USB. And you must not save files to the same disk that you're recovering from, so get an external disk as well.

In order to install TestDisk on the Live Ubuntu session, you must enable the *universe* section of the Ubuntu repositories. Then update and install as normal.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help i don't have external HDD nor my friends have it :( . I've already installed Windows XP I'll use "TestDisk" in Windows XP & try to recover as much as possible.

Comment: Now nothing can be done only an miracle can help me get back my files.

Comment: Well, that's not true. Windows XP isn't _that_ big and only the parts that have actually been overwritten, is overwritten. But stop using Windows immediately and use photorec from Ubuntu live. The more you use Windows, the less chance you have of getting your files back, because it will keep writing data to the disk, when you want _not_ to write data. The worst thing you can ever do when you get a data disaster, is to panic. Just switch off and do nothing until you've consulted an expert, is always the best advise.

Comment: I had used "EaseUS Data Recovery" software & it managed to recover 90% of the files :) :) :) ... & I was happy that it could even retain the folder names & original directory tree.

Comment: Ah, that's great to hear! It's easy to forget that with a large disk, even if you install an OS, most of it is not overwritten. If you don't panic, then you have good chances to recover stuff :)